# Angular 8 | Hide element using Directive

Tags: html, angular8

I want to hide specific element using Directive in Angular 8 when user click on input field.
Code is as per below

**HTML**

```html
<input [choosecountry] type="text" />
```

**directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[choosecountry]'
})

export class ChoosecountryDirective {  

    constructor( ) { }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular already have `ngIf` to accomblish this piece of requirement.

Comment: Thanks,
I am new in Angular world, but i solved it using ngIf

Comment: Yes, that's what I recommended in my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[hidden]="true"` this element will created on DOM as hidden, which is opposite to `ngIf`

Answer (score -2):

yes, using Directive you can hide or show element.[here is an example](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/building-real-world-angular-2-apps/authentication-based-directives)